# Comparing the current line with the previous one. Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, if-statement, spring-mybatis

I want to compare the current line with the previous one, and if they match, do the calculation. If not, assign 0.0 My code only computes without accepting the condition.

for example i have table: oil
oil consist a month, date and an indicator

And it have to look like:

```
Month      Values  Date        |formula              |Growth
september   100     01.09.2020  |(100/nan - 1) * 100  |infinity
september   80      08.09.2020  |(80/100-1) * 100     |-20
september   100     15.09.2020  |(100/80-1) * 100     |25     
october     118     01.10.2020  |september != october |0
october     120     08.10.2020  |(120/118-1) * 100    |1.69                 
october     123     15.10.2020  |(123/120-1) * 100    |2.5
november    122     01.11.2020  |october != november  |0
november    122     08.11.2020  |(122/122-1) * 100    |0
```

My class model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "oper_mon_oil_price")

public class OilModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@Column(name = "o_year")
private String oyear;
@Column(name = "o_month")
private String omonth;
@Column(name = "o_date_event")
private String odateEvent;
@Column(name = "o_period")
private String operiod;
@Column(name = "o_area")
private String oarea;
@Column(name = "o_unit")
private String ounit;
@Column(name = "o_ai_92")
public Double oai92;
@Column(name = "o_ai_95")
public Double oai95;
@Column(name = "o_diesel_winter")
private Double odieselWinter;
@Column(name = "o_diesel_fuel_offseason")
private Double odieselFuelOffseason;
@Column(name = "growth_ai_92")
public Double growthAi92;
@Column(name = "growth_ai_95")
public Double growthAi95;
@Column(name = "growth_diesel_winter")
public Double growthDieselWinter;
@Column(name = "growth_diesel_fuel_offseason")
public Double growthDieselFuelOffseason;
 
getters/setters
}
```

class repository:

```
@Repository
@Mapper
public interface OilProdTovRepo {

@Select("SELECT * FROM oper_mon_prod_tov ORDER BY o_year ASC, o_month ASC, o_date_event ASC ")
@Results(value ={
        @Result(property = "id",column = "id"),
        @Result(property = "area",column = "o_area"),
        @Result(property = "year",column = "o_year"),
        @Result(property = "month",column = "o_month"),
        @Result(property = "period",column = "o_period"),
        @Result(property = "dateEvent",column = "o_date_event"),
        @Result(property = "unit",column = "o_unit"),
        @Result(property = "wheatFlourFirstGrade",column = "o_wheat_flour_first_grade"),
        @Result(property = "wheatBread",column = "o_wheat_bread"),
        @Result(property = "horns",column = "o_horns"),
        @Result(property = "buckwheat",column = "o_buckwheat"),
        @Result(property = "polishedRice",column = "o_polished_rice"),
        @Result(property = "potato",column = "o_potato"),
        @Result(property = "carrots",column = "o_carrots"),
        @Result(property = "onion",column = "o_onion"),
        @Result(property = "cabbageWhite",column = "o_cabbage_white"),
        @Result(property = "sugar",column = "o_sugar"),
        @Result(property = "oil",column = "o_oil"),
        @Result(property = "beef",column = "o_beef"),
        @Result(property = "chickenMeat",column = "o_chicken_meat"),
        @Result(property = "milk",column = "o_milk"),
        @Result(property = "kefir",column = "o_kefir"),
        @Result(property = "butter",column = "o_butter"),
        @Result(property = "egg",column = "o_egg"),
        @Result(property = "salt",column = "o_salt"),
        @Result(property = "cottageCheese",column = "o_cottage_cheese"),
        @Result(property = "growthWheatFlourFirstGrade",column = "o_growth_wheat_flour_first_grade"),

})
List<OilProdTovModel> getOilProdTovModel();

@Update("UPDATE oper_mon_prod_tov SET o_growth_wheat_flour_first_grade=#{growthWheatFlourFirstGrade} WHERE id=#{id}")
void updateWheatFlourFirstGrade(OilProdTovModel oilProdTovModel);
}
```

And the main class, Service :

```
@Service
public class OilProdTovService {
@Autowired
public OilProdTovRepo oilProdTovRepo;

public List<OilProdTovModel> allOilProdTov() {
    List<OilProdTovModel> oilProdTovModels = oilProdTovRepo.getOilProdTovModel();
    Double first = 0.0;
    Double result;
    for (OilProdTovModel oilProdTovModel : oilProdTovModels) {
        if (oilProdTovModel.getMonth().equals("September")) {
            Double wheatFlourFirstGrade = oilProdTovModel.getWheatFlourFirstGrade();
            result = (wheatFlourFirstGrade / first - 1) * 100;
            first = wheatFlourFirstGrade;
            wheatFlourFirstGrade = result;
            oilProdTovModel.setGrowthWheatFlourFirstGrade(wheatFlourFirstGrade);
        } else if (oilProdTovModel.getMonth().equals("October")) {
            Double wheatFlourFirstGrade = oilProdTovModel.getWheatFlourFirstGrade();
            result = (wheatFlourFirstGrade / first - 1) * 100;
            first = wheatFlourFirstGrade;
            wheatFlourFirstGrade = result;
            oilProdTovModel.setGrowthWheatFlourFirstGrade(wheatFlourFirstGrade);
        }
        else if (oilProdTovModel.getMonth().equals("November")) {
            Double wheatFlourFirstGrade = oilProdTovModel.getWheatFlourFirstGrade();
            result = (wheatFlourFirstGrade / first - 1) * 100;
            first = wheatFlourFirstGrade;
            wheatFlourFirstGrade = result;
            oilProdTovModel.setGrowthWheatFlourFirstGrade(wheatFlourFirstGrade);
        }
        else {
            oilProdTovModel.setGrowthWheatFlourFirstGrade(0.0);
        }
        
        oilProdTovRepo.updateWheatFlourFirstGrade(oilProdTovModel);
    }
    return oilProdTovRepo.getOilProdTovModel();
}
}
```

How i can modified my code ?

Comment: what exactly is the part that doesn't work? Is it just me, or do you have a lot of duplicate code in there?

Comment: Your example table says uses all lower case for months, like `september`, but your code asks for `September`?

Comment: You're asking about comparing lines but only show entities and a service so are the "lines" only output and a representation of your entities? In that case what's the problem with comparing 2 entities?

Comment: @Thomas I do not know how to do it

Comment: Does that mean you don't know how to get adjacent elements in an array or list and compare those objects or individual properties? In your loop just keep track of the last element you've visited and compare it to the one of the current iteration.

Comment: @GhostCat how i can modified code, that asks for September

Comment: @Thomas i tried, but it didn't work for me :( Can you show example ?

Comment: I'll add an answer for the example but let me add one suggestion here: since you're struggling with that kind of problem already you seem to be very new to programming and are probably dealing with frameworks too complex for you yet. Try to get a grasp of the basics first.

Comment: What? Are you really asking how you have to change `if (oilProdTovModel.getMonth().equals("September"))` so that it compares to `september`, and not `September`? Seriously?

Comment: And I agree with @Thomas. If you really struggle with comparing Strings with ignoring casing, then you are absolutely overburdening yourself right now. Or is all of this just some exercise, not meant for "real world" usage? But even then: step back, and start with code that you have a chance of understanding and fixing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to struggle with getting hold of 2 entities that follow each other in list here's how you could do it:

Using "foreach":

```
List<OilProdTovModel> oilProdTovModels = ...
OilProdTovModel prev = null;
for (OilProdTovModel oilProdTovModel : oilProdTovModels) {
  if( prev != null ) {
    //compare oilProdTovModel and prev here
  }

  prev = oilProdTovModel; //keep track of the current element to serve as prev for the next iteration
}
```

Using a traditional for loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < oilProdTovModels.size(); i++) {
  OilProdTovModel prev = oilProdTovModels.get(i - 1);
  OilProdTovModel current = oilProdTovModels.get(i);

  //compare both - if you need to handle the first element without any comparison then do that before the loop 
  //(or iterate from 0 to size() - 1 and handle the last element after the loop if needed)
}
```

Comment: did I write the code correctly?  my code: [link](https://prnt.sc/10ozvhn). DB: [link](https://prnt.sc/10ozxm1)

Comment: @хххххх well, it _looks_ ok but I can't really tell because I don't know all the requirements and your enviroment (and digging into all of this is way too much for SO). Do the results look correct? Did you step through your code with a debugger and does it do what you want?